# How to save form data using a custom button in Openerp/Odoo

Tags: forms, button, odoo, odoo-8

We have a form with fields. We have added our own "Save" button, and want to persist the data on the form to the server when this button is clicked.

We know how to create actions on the server to handle button clicks, but no idea how to retrieve the form data.

Currently, we are using the inbuilt Save button but need to trigger some extra functionality hence the request.

This is what our XML looks like currently.

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="petra_ticket_hold_dialog">
        <field name="name">petra.ticket_request.hold.dialog</field>
        <field name="model">petra.ticket_request</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Hold Ticket" edit="false" create="false" delete="false">
                <sheet>
                    <group colspan="2">
                        <field name="hold_reason"/>
                        <field name="status" invisible="1"/>
                    </group>
                    <button string="Save" />
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to add the extra functionality to the existing "Save" function, instead of adding a new alternative one?

Comment: We've only been doing odoo for 5 days now. Sadly the documentation is not too great. We'd appreciate it if you can show us how or point us the the right direction.

Comment: So I just looked it up and that wont work for us. Basically, we have a dialog and need to close the dialog after the save button. Overriding the save function requires us to return true or false so we can't return the action to close the window.

Comment: Is it a wizard then? and you want to store what you complete in the wizard?

Comment: @dccdany Once you click a button to close the ticket, we open a dialog that requests you to enter the solution. In the dialog, we show you only the reason dialog which updates the ticket once saved. During our investigation, a wizard was suggested. Do you think it will be better to use that? If so, any good resources on implementing it in v8?

Comment: To think of it, a wizard makes a lot of sense. I'll see what I can find on my own as well.

Comment: If you tell me a use case i can help you with that, for example, you got a field in the main form (ticket), when you want to close a ticket you need to parse the solution in a ticket field, lets say, "Solution". But, that field will only can be writed from a new window (Wizard). If thats the case, its pretty simple.

Comment: We have a ticket model. One of the fields on the model is solution. However we don't display it on the form. When a user wants to close the ticket, he clicks a "close"  button which has an action on the server that opens a window with the solution field and a hidden "status"  field so when the solution changes we update it to closed. How can we achieve this with a wizard?

Comment: Do I understand correctly? You have some `main` form. When user click on some link you show `petra_ticket_hold_dialog`. You want to create custom handler on click *Save* on server-side and close dialog. Is it right?

Comment: Exactly! @DanilaGanchar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a small example which can help you. First of all you need to add some action of model to button like this:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="petra_ticket_hold_dialog">
        <field name="name">petra.ticket_request.hold.dialog</field>
        <field name="model">petra.ticket_request</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Hold Ticket" edit="false" create="false" delete="false">
                <sheet>
                    <group colspan="2">
                        <field name="hold_reason"/>
                        <field name="status" invisible="1"/>
                    </group>
                    <!-- it means that will be calls method 'action_my_action' of object 'petra.ticket_request' -->
                    <button string="Save" name="action_my_action" type="object"/>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

After this you need to add method to your model:

```
# you can use @api.multi for collection processing like this:
# for ticket in self: ...something do here
# or you can use @api.model for processing only one object
@api.model
def action_my_action(self):
    # here you have values from form and context
    print(self.hold_reason, self._context)
    # todo something here... and close dialog
    return {'type': 'ir.actions.act_window_close'}
```

Restart *openerp-server* and update your module.

Be careful! Object will be saved in db before your `action_my_action`.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know I could use self to retrieve the values. Excellent! Thanks again.

Comment: api.model fails for me but api.one works. Error was something about being unable to convert to sequence.

Comment: @frostymarvelous oh sorry. It is because I work with v.9. api.one - deprecated in odoo 9.

Comment: O OK. Tried using 9 but had issues so reverted to 8 since the documentation available is mainly for 8.